# gcm getMessageType(intent) always return null

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I can only get null for the messageType when I called the function gcm.getMessageType(intent) in the class which I extended the IntentService. I'm sure the intent parameter is the intent I received in your BroadcastReceiver.

In the page [GCM returns a null message type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983184/gcm-returns-a-null-message-type) they said the problem is more or less related to the manifest file, but I checked my file and could not find the reason. The example I use is from http://www.grokkingandroid.com/?s=gcm&x=0&y=0.

My AndroidManifest.xml is provided as below. Much appreciated if someone can help me to figure it out. I am stuck in this problem for several days.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission
    android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/gcm_demo_app_name"
    android:theme="@style/DemoAppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm.GCMDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/gcm_demo_title_activity_gcm_demo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.ACTION_START" />

            <data
                android:host="grokkingandroid.com"
                android:path="/samples/gcm demo"
                android:scheme="app" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.alert.AlertListActivity"
        android:label="@string/Emergency_warning" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.description.DescriptionActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/gcm_demo_title_activity_description" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.grokkingandroid.sampleapp.samples.gcm.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: Its not necessarily the case. Can you share your Broadcast Receiver?